How to run a python script without opening docker pseudo tty?
I have a docker image which has gdal libraries and my python code using said libraries. I start into the docker image with 'docker run -v path/to/mydata:/data -it localhost/software --name xyz' and then run my python code as 'python Processes.py arguments', it runs perfectly fine.
I tried with 'docker run -v path/to/mydata:/data localhost/software --name xyz /path/to/python/inside/image/python /path/to/mysoftware/Processes.py arguments', it says that it cannot find libgdal.so.
Edit:
Sample of the issue.


can you trying running your command like docker run -v path/to/mydata:/data localhost/software --name xyz  bash -c 'python Processes.py' ?

Just tried. Same issue. /bin/bash and bash. Both gave the same issue.

@AlbinPaul When I remove the whole path for python, it says python: command not found I tried with both variations of bash calling and full path to python

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], including all source code, required inputs, and outputs in plain text?

(The command line you show looks like you're trying to run a short-lived Python program to read and write local files, and you may find this easier to do without Docker in a Python virtual environment.  Your Dockerfile should be using the Debian APT tools to install the GDAL shared libraries with this setup.)

That is not possible for me. This is just part of the tool. There is a whole another setup which is in R which we have to share. I have to give docker image to a team which will run on their server. It's a set of tools developed by different people which will be used by another team.

@DavidMaze I have written code to reproduce the issue. Screenshot is showing the error. I can add the error to the text though.

Since the error is that the libgdal.so file cannot be found, I guess that it is not properly getting installed inside the docker container, since the symlink is not getting created correctly. Maybe do "sudo install --package" and then "sudo apt update and upgrade". Or if you can post your docker file, that might help.

I didn't make the dockerfile. But from what I was told, the library was installed outside the docker (rather than using dockerfile) to install it. Then it was copied and the image saved. My question is if the installation is bad, how can I go into the container and run it. Also, it is a redhat server that the other team uses it. There is no internet connection for me to update it. The reason why I cannot use my own gdal environment is because it is the image I have to finally use as they data that gets processesed is passed to me which I then pass to some other module.

If all else fails the only option I see is a different docker image with gdal as primary installation and install python into it.

After a quick google search I found the following GitHub project: https://github.com/andrii-rieznik/docker-python-gdal - Maybe give it a try and if it works compare this Dockerfile with your Dockerfile. If this is working, you could build it on a different machine and copy the image to the server with no internet connection.

@bySimpson I'll go home, build this and upload it to drive. Come back to the office, test it, and let you know in 12 hours. Thanks. This seems like a possible solution, installing both Python and Gdal was a big hassle earlier.

Can you try: docker run -v path/to/mydata:/data -e LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libgdal.so/directory localhost/software --name xyz /path/to/python/inside/image/python /path/to/mysoftware/Processes.py arguments ?

@matleg It solved it. Write the answer. I can award the bounty. I checked the docker image. I found out that the gdal library installed in python path didn't have libgdal when looking for the path you mentioned above. It was installed in the docker somewhere else. But, the path is not updated I think when I launch from outside. Please also specify how to make the path permanent as I don't want to keep this user dependent.

I also want to know why the path differs, can't wrap my head around it.

Can share what is your base image? Is it public? My guess is you are overriding default startup script, so you can give output from docker inspect $your_image and there should be Cmd field

It's not a public image. It's derived from redhat docker image but a lot of modules by different people were added into it. I was given that image with R and Python with GDAL. It's in a system which cannot copy stuff to internet but I can copy stuff from Internet with multiple approvals. That's why it's annoying for me to make any docker image.

Can you paste Cmd & Entrypoint fields here?

I'll write the answer as suggested in the comments though I know it is only partial and does not answer your second comment: "I also want to know why the path differs". Hopefully it will help to find a better one.
Initially I suspected that the python interpreter adds some environment variable(s) when started but it does not. A solution consists in either adding the environment variable in the command line when running the docker image:
docker run -v path/to/mydata:/data -e LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libgdal.so/directory localhost/software --name xyz /path/to/python/inside/image/python /path/to/mysoftware/Processes.py

or adding a line to the dockerfile (hence making it available to all users):
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libgdal.so/directory:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

or setting it in the shell directly and permanently in .bashrc or profile file for example:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/libgdal.so/directory:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

As suggested by @zori in the comments, you can inspect the image. You can also inspect your environment variables both with the script or the python interpreter and see what differs:
import os

print("LD_LIBRARY_PATH:", os.getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH'))
print("PYTHONPATH:", os.getenv('PYTHONPATH'))


My question was, why was the other path for libgdal available to the same python when I'm inside the docker environment. Thanks for the solution though.

The second part was not part of the original question, I'd be unfair if I didn't award the bounty. I'm still unable to explain it though.
